# What's the best way to use thresholding to detect light regions inside a image using OpenCV library?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filter, computer-vision

I have the following image and would like to extract small light circles within a bigger dark gray circle

[image]

I used some filters in OpenCV to study how the thresholding would impact the final outcome.

```
org_img = cv2.imread(fn,0)
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(org_img, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2GRAY)
blur_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_img,(11,11),10)
fig,ax = try_all_threshold(blur_img,figsize=(10,10), verbose=True)
plt.show(fig)
```

Outcomes are :

[image]

Although it shows bigger ones, I am trying to detect even the smaller ones at the edges.

[image]

What techniques could I try to enhance the difference of lighter and darker regions in this?

Deep learning based segemetataion technique could not get anything close to what I get with above traditional techniques consistantly on multiple images.

Comment: those features are at the edge of perceivability even for humans. you'd have a hard time arguing for some of your yellow arrows, like the bottom left one. you'll need **AI**. low level image processing won't catch this.

Comment: What @Christoph said, but instead of AI, what you need is magic and/or wishful thinking. You won’t detect some of those most faint dots in this image. If it is important to detect those, you will have to improve your image acquisition.